# Trouble multiprocessing - "The parameter is incorrect" on p.start()

Tags: python, parameters, multiprocessing

I've been having a lot of trouble multiprocessing - I've literally been trying for hours and can't get it right. Here's my code, commented the best I could do.

### Linked all my code as I don't know what's causing it exactly.

### Line 74 it says, on p.start()

### The most relevant part of code is the bottom of the question.

Here are my imports

```
import urllib
import socket
import multiprocessing as mp
import queue
import requests
```

Header used for higher chance of success upon connecting to a website

```
headers={'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
```

Main function takes four parameters - queue, the URL List, the Output file, and the list of vulnerable URLs.

```
def mainFunction(q, URLList, Output, vulnURLS):
```

This list is used to check if the page source has any of the errors in the list after adding a string query to the end of the url (')

```
    queries = ['SQL syntax', 'mysql_fetch', 'mysql_num_rows', 'mySQL Error', 'mySQL_connect()', 'UNION SELECT', 'MySQL server version']
```

This puts the URL in the correct format before testing for injection points.

```
    URLReplace = [("['", ""),("']",""), ("\n", ""), ("https://","http://"), ("\s", "%20"), ("\s", "%20")]
    URL = ''.join(str(URLList))
    for URL in URLList:
        if (z < len(URLReplace)):
            URL = URL.replace(URLReplace[z])
        z = z + 1
        URL = (URL + "'")
```

This is the try request, where it attempts to connect and scrapes the HTML off of the webpage.

```
    try:
        req = requests.get(URL, timeout=2)
        htmlObject = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
```

This iterates through the list to check for any possible vulnerabilities. Also returns 404/400 messages.

```
        if (y < len(queries)):
            if queries[x] in htmlObject:
                print ("\t [+] " + URL)
                vulnURLS.append(URL)
                Output.open()
                for VURLS in vulnURLS:
                    Output.write(VURLS + '\n')
                Output.close()
            y = y + 1
        else:
            print ("\t [-] " + URL)
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
            if e.code == 404:
            print("\t [-] Page not found.")
            if e.code == 400:
                print ("\t [+] " + URL) 
        except urllib.error.URLError as e:
            print("\t [-] URL Timed Out")
        except socket.timeout as e:
            print("\t [-] URL Timed Out")
        except socket.error as e:
            print("\t [-] Error in URL")
```

- ### Here's the important part, where I use the Queue & multiprocessor.

  ```
  if __name__=='__main__':
      q = mp.Queue()
      URLList = [i.strip().split() for i in open('sites.txt').readlines()]
      Output = open('output.txt', 'r')
      vulnURLS = []
      p = mp.Process(target=mainFunction, args=(q, URLList, Output, vulnURLS))
      p.start()
      q.put(mainFunction(URLList))
      q.close()
      q.join_thread()
      p.join()
  ```

Please help me out with this problem, I've been stuck on it for hours and am getting very frustrated that I cannot follow the solution. Every module I look at I follow to a T and get this same error.

I have tried multi-threading, but it is extremely slow and unstable when compared to multiprocessing.

Answer (score -1):

Change to the following:

```
p = mp.Process(target=mainFunction, args=(q, Output))
p.start()

for url in URLList:
     q.put(url)
```